# Please select a file error

Tags: plugins, uploads, installation

I am facing `Please select a file` error while trying to upload a plugin. My `php.ini` settings are like below

- upload_max_filesize = 20000
- max_file_uploads = 200
- max_execution_time = 300
- max_input_time = 600
- memory_limit = 12800
- post_max_size = 8000

My WordPress Version 5.5.3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is a hosting issue. Contact your hosting company support. If it is in the localhost server then there may have a permission issue ...