# Debugging in WordPress at Theme installation

Tags: themes, debug

I am trying to upload a Theme. But I am getting message `Please select a file`.

[image]

I placed below code in `wp-config.php` file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

My PHP Version is `7.4.18`

My server settings are like below

[image]

My Server file & folder permission is like below

[image]

But I am not getting any Debug Log message.

[image]

I am trying to install [this](https://wordpress.org/themes/house-state/) Theme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please select a file error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378636/please-select-a-file-error)

Comment: If it's in the plugin directory can you not just install it straight from there on the site? You don't need to download it and re-upload it I don't think.

Comment: But you can always just unzip the theme into the right place, which is in the wp-content/themes folder so that all the files end up in a folder named after the theme, particularly if this is all on your own laptop.

Comment: Thanks @Rup. I know that but I would like to solve the issue . Thanks.

Comment: @ShahAlom vai, your solution is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I did answer previously in a same question - [Please select a file error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378636/please-select-a-file-error) .

Not sure, if it will help.

Comment: vai, I tried this. But result is like before.